# logwatch no mail for root no output

Tags: logging, output

I'm having some trouble with logwatch on a debian machine.  When cron runs it I get an email like this:

```
    /etc/cron.daily/00logwatch:
You have old files in your logwatch tmpdir (/tmp):
    logwatch.vgravfXz
    logwatch.VQCUc9AZ
    logwatch.CogZiLf0
The directories listed above were most likely created by a
logwatch run that failed to complete successfully.  If so, you
may delete these directories.

No mail for root
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/00logwatch exited with return code 141
```

If I run logwatch at the prompt it just says "no mail for root."  But it works great on another debian machine (jessie 8.6 both.)  And several ubuntu 14 and 16 machines work fine too.  This machine has lots of activity so I don't get why there's no output.

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was going on, but I re-installed debian and now logwatch works great.  I guess sometimes, even with a stable linux distro, a wipe and fresh install does the trick.  No clue what caused the problem to begin with ...